# Backend response value is empty when endpoint is called from React component even though network call shows response body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a React component that makes a call out to an endpoint. It looks like this:

```
const UnstyledLanding = ({ className }) => {
    const [resumeUrl, setResumeUrl] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${functionsRequest}/resume`, {
            mode: 'no-cors'
        }).then(response => {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(url => {
            console.log("resume url: ", url);
            setResumeUrl(url);
        });
    }, []);

... 
}
```

Nothing is logged out for the "resume url" value, and my resumeUrl state is never set. However, I see the value when I look at the response for that endpoint call in my network tab, so the endpoint seems to be getting called correctly. This is a Firebase app, and I'm calling out to a Firebase Cloud Function that I've defined in my functions folder. I'm running the functions emulator locally, which is running on `localhost:5001`. Would really appreciate any insight into why the value isn't being returned in my React component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of your `mode: 'no-cors'` flag in the fetch options. When you make a request using `'no-cors'` to a cross-origin resource (in this case the Firebase servers I imagine), it returns an opaque response, which doesn't return any data on its body.